# Frame redirect with variables PHP

Tags: php, redirect, subdomain

I have a webbhosting server at a fixed address lets say server.com and I have another domain which is name.com. I have created a subdomain which is test.name.com and I want this to redirect to my new server, server.com. So if I type test.name.com it should redirect to server.com.
In my other hosting company where I have test.name.com subdomain I redirected it to server.com using frame redirect and it works fine except for one thing. How do I pass variables around?

Lets say I type test.name.com/?price=21, I want it to redirect it to server.com/?price=21 so that I should be able to extract the variable using PHP _GET at my new server. Is this possible? I only have the option for redirect using 301 server or frame redirect it seems. Thanks!

Comment: `header('Location: http://server.com');` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I would recommend doing a redirect with .htaccess You will have father more control than with a frame redirect.

Comment: I do not have the possibility to access .htaccess. I can only choose between server redirect 301 or frame redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parse_url()** to split the URI and then redirect.

```
<?php
    $req = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $newserver = "server.com";

    header("location: ".$req['scheme']."://".$newserver.$req['path']."?".$req['query']);
?>
```

Comment: Im new to this PHP and server world. Where would I do this?

Comment: Just create any php file inside your server. When some user request the url, it will be redirecter to the new site. You can do this in htaccess (more elegant way), but your question is tagged with **PHP**

Comment: Im sorry I do not think I am clear enough. I do not have acces to the webservice where my domains are. I can only choose between server redirect 301 or frame redirect.

Comment: You must have access to the server to do this.

Comment: Is that the only way? If yes than I can just leave it as it is :)

Comment: Two ways to redirect: 1. Including a rule in .htaccess (apache) 2. Redirecting by header("location:...") in PHP (explained below)